# STR_TO_DATE in MySql gives error

Tags: mysql

I am facing some problem with STR_TO_DATE in mysql. The following is returning NULL.

```
select str_to_date('2012-04-28 23:00:15', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s');
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need capital `%H`, not a lowercase `%h`.

According to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format),

> %H    Hour (00..23)
>   %h    Hour (01..12)

Answer (score 1):

Can use also:

str_to_date('2012-04-28 23:00:15', '%Y-%m-%d %T')